# How to add a char to the end of an array with a defined length in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a C assignment where we use an array with a length of 10 to store chars into. The professor made a point where we can't use null to specify the end of the array. The array is to hold a name and we read from stdin. When the name is bigger than 10 characters, we print out it's too long. Here is my code so far and it doesn't work because when I press enter to submit the name, it uses that as a character and I have to get to 10 before anything happens, which results in it saying it's too long of a name, which isn't the desired result.

```
int main( void )
{
  printf( "What's your name: " );

  // Storage for a name, as an array of characters without a null
  // marking the end.
  char name[ 10 ];
  int len = 0;

  char ch = getchar();
  while((ch != EOF) || (ch != '\n')) {
    name[10] = name[10] + ch;
    ch = getchar();
    len++;
    if(len > 10) {
      printf("That name is too long.");
    }
  }

  printf("Hello ");
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("%c", name[i]);
  }

  printf(".\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try “executing” your program using pen and paper.  Then step through it in a debugger to see what it actually does and where this diverges from your expectation.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I feel like name[10] = name[10] + ch isn't correct. I didn't know if there was a way to just add a character to an array

Comment: I too have a feeling that this isn't correct. ;-)  When you print out the array, you are indexing it correctly.  Use the same approach for filling it.  Of course, your whole program could be written in three lines of code using `fgets` and `printf`  and it would even be more efficient.

Comment: `char ch` should be `int ch`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think this is the program you are aiming for:

```
int main( void )
{
    // Storage for a name, as an array of characters without a null marking the end.
    char name[ 10 ];
    int len = 0;
    printf( "What's your name: " );

    ch = getchar();
    while((ch != EOF) || (ch != '\n'))
    {
        name[len] = ch;
        len++;
        if(len > 10) {
            printf("That name is too long.");
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }

    name[len]='\0';

    printf("Hello ");
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%c", name[i]);
    }

    printf(".\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here `name[len]='\0';` is used to terminate your char array.

Comment: In my opinion, a code dump with little or no explanation to a homework question is not the best service we can provide.  And at least the `(ch != EOF) || (ch != '\n')` thing is still wrong.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't using the len variable in the correct way. It makes sense to use that as the index of the array. Thank you. And I found my while loop error a few minutes ago, thank you 5gon12eder!

Comment: This won't even compile!

Answer (score 4):

Despite it's name, `getchar` returns an `int`, not a character.   The value of `EOF` generally cannot be represented in an `unsigned char` (the only type of character value that `getchar` can return).   No value of type `unsigned char` can ever test equal to `EOF`.

Also look carefully at the condition of your `while` loop.   It is always true, so you have an infinite loop, even if you store the result of `getchar` in something other than `char`.

`name[10] = name[10] + ch`  also does not have the desired effect.